# how to create a vpc across multiple regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

People say "VPC is region specific - meaning vpc exists in the region in which it was created". Is it true? If so, why create-vpc doesn't have an option to choose region? What if I want to replicate a VPC in multiple regions?

[create-vpc doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-vpc.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> meaning vpc exists in the region in which it was created"

Yes

> create-vpc doesn't have an option to choose region

By default the user's default region is used, possible to override using the `--region` parameter.

The `--region`  parameter belongs to the aws cli level (not just ec2), so it is documented elsewhere

> What if I want to replicate a VPC in multiple regions

I'm not sure what do you mean by *replicate*, you may create a vpc with the same properties in each region. Each vpc is region-specific, so the VPCs in each region are separate and not connected whatsoever.

It is possible to connect multiple VPC in different regions using VPN or Inter-region VPC peering. Anyway I'd advice to keep systems between regions separate or use aws-native replication if really needed.

Comment: Thank you @gusto2, --region option is neither exposed in the UI nor in aws cli create-vpc doc. any thoughts?

Comment: @Arjun the [region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-options.html) parameter is documented and in the UI (aws mngt console) you can see  which region you are working in